# Buildroot: how to add libraries

Tags: libraries, libc, buildroot, libdl

I am working on a buildroot project to make a small custom os. I only include the absolute necessary packages. One of the things I add is a precompiled program that uses certain libraries that are not included on the system. I want the system to include them, but I cannot find them in the buildroot `menuconfig`, `linux-menuconfig` or `busybox-menuconfig`.

So my question is: 
**how do I add libraries to my system in buildroot?**

I have tried searching for them in the menuconfigs and I have also tried to find information about this in the buildroot manual.

The libraries I want to include are:

```
ld-linux-armhf.so.3
libdl.so.2
libc.so.6
```

After some searching I have found that:

- `ld-linux-armhf.so.3` is actually a symlink to a `ld-2.*.*.so` library
- A version of `libc` is included on my system (`libc.so.2`).

Answer (score 1):

The libraries you list are part of the C library, itself part of the toolchain. Buildroot will always provide those libraries, either by building a toolchain itself (what we call the *internal toolchain backend*) or by using an existing toolchain (what we call the *external toolchain backend*).

Comment: So how do I give the directive that those will be copied to the actual OS? Since they are not present in the final build.